# Error al Llamar datos de tablas de diferentes base de datos LARAVEL - AJAX

Tags: sql, laravel, ajax

estoy que llamo datos de una tabla de diferente base de datos, a la que tengo por defecto con Laravel. Mi problema es que al momento de hacer la carga todo sale bien pero los datos llamados no aparecen en las cajas de texto a las cuales quiero poner. Estoy llamando los datos con ajax y por consola se pueden ver que los datos vienen correctamente pero no aparecen en las cajas de texto.

Aqui mi codigo:

Mi Modelo

```
public static function buscarEmpleado($dni){
        return DB::select("SELECT 
                            ApellidoPaterno,
                            ApellidoMaterno,
                            Nombres
                            FROM BASE2.dbo.Empleados WHERE DNI = '$dni'");
}
```

Mi Controlador:

```
public function Buscar(Request $request){
        $dni = $request->text;

        $data = Empleado::buscarEmpleado($dni);

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Mi Vista:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ApellidoPaterno" maxlength="30" id="bDNI">
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary m-btn m-btn--icon" id="buscar">
Buscar</a>
<input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="40" id="Nombres" >
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ApellidoPaterno">
<input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="30" id="ApellidoMaterno" >
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#buscar').on('click', function(){

            var dni = $('#bDNI').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Administracion/Usuario_Personal/buscarDNI",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", text: dni},
                success: function (response) {
                $('#ApellidoPaterno').val(response.ApellidoPaterno);
                $('#ApellidoMaterno').val(response.ApellidoMaterno);
                $('#Nombres').val(response.Nombres);
                alert('a: '+response.ApellidoPaterno);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
0:
ApellidoMaterno: "Cuadrado"
ApellidoPaterno: "Mimbela"
Nombres: "Erick Sebastian"
```

En la parte de la vista pongo una alert para ver el dato al cual estoy llamando y me sale indefinido. Donde esta el error entonces?

Comment: Podrías hacer un `console.log(response)` y pegar lo que devuelve?

Comment: @azeós ahi esta, ya lo puse

Comment: Aparece así sin llaves, corchetes, nada? Copialo textual por las dudas. El `alert` se abre, no?

Comment: @azeós si sale normal con las llaves, en el alert solo sale "undefined"

Comment: Pegalo con las llaves. Si hacés un `console.log(response[0].ApellidoPaterno)`?

Comment: @azeós si man ya salio, resulta que tenia que ponerlo asi como dices response[0].ApellidoPaterno al momento de poner asi salio todo normal. Gracias!

Comment: Porque estás retornado un array. Ahora te respondo para explicar un poco mejor lo que podrías hacer.

Comment: @azeós ok seria mejor gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta a la DB devuelve una `collection` (un array), por eso no podes acceder directamente a `response.ApellidoPaterno`, tenés que acceder a `response[0].ApellidoPaterno`.

Ahora, hacer eso no es correcto. O tu consulta devuelve un único resultado (que es probablemente lo que quieras porque estás buscando por DNI), o devuelve varios y deberías contemplarlo desde JS.

**Modelo:**

```
public static function buscarEmpleado($dni) {
    return DB::table('BASE2.dbo.Empleados')
        ->select('ApellidoPaterno', 'ApellidoMaterno', 'Nombres')
        ->where('DNI', $dni)
        ->first();
}
```

Al usar [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) el Query Builder devuelve un único resultado y no una `collection`. Con lo cual ahora si vas a poder acceder directamente a `response.ApellidoPaterno`.

Cambié tu consulta para usar los métodos del Query Builder que me parece un poco más prolijo. De hecho si podes usar [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) hasta sería mejor. Pero no se como tenés definido el modelo.

Con Eloquent sería algo así:

```
public static function buscarEmpleado($dni) {
    return self::where('DNI', $dni)->first(['ApellidoPaterno', 'ApellidoMaterno', 'Nombres']);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por explicación man, me sirvio y saco de dudas!